# executing user input as code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to step through and evaluate user defined formulas in a worksheet (i.e. they would be strings).
The text may look something like (syntax could be changed to make the vba code writing easier):

```
Var1('a,1') = 0.1
Var1('a,2') = 0.5
Var2('a') = Var1('a,1') + Var2('a,2')
Var3('a') = SomeFunction(Var2('a'),"SomeArg")
etc.
```

If I could wrap each line in something like Execute(Line) then it seems straightforward, is this possible?

The only other method I've been able to think of is having a dictionary store the variables, but then I'll need to write some (probably bug filled) code to wrap the  variable names but not the function names.

```
VarDict("Var1('a,1')") = 0.1
VarDict("Var1('a,2')") = 0.5
VarDict("Var2('a')") = VarDict("Var1('a,1')") + VarDict("Var2('a,2')")
VarDict("Var3('a')") = SomeFunction(VarDict("Var2('a')"),"SomeArg")
etc.
```

Comment: You mean like providing an API layer on top of the VBA layer in an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: [Application.Evaluate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx)

Comment: @James: I guess so, although it would mostly be simple formula operators.

Comment: @GSerg: my understanding is that Evaluate will do the RHS of an equation but won't allow you to assign the output to a variable based on the string?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a little of topic but I would suggest taking a look at [pyspread](http://manns.github.io/pyspread/) it is a spreadsheet that allows each cell to be any python object up to and including a full python program - if you are not tied into Excel then you will find a lot of the work done for you.

*N.B. [python](http://python.org), pyspread and all the required tools, ([wxpython](http://wxpython.org) for the GUI, [numpy](http://numpy.org) for the numeric libraries, gpg for signing spreadsheets securely, etc), are free, (including for commercial use), and will run on multiple platforms including Windows, Macintosh and Linux amongst others.*

Comment: Thanks for the link Steve. Unfortunately I am tied to Excel, otherwise I'd probably just try to do it in Python. Although your suggestion would have it in the familiar spreadsheet interface.